# Сортировка по FTP и SSH(терминал)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ftp, sh

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить ls в баше сортировать файлы так же как это происходит по ftp, то есть все с точкой идет первым

```
ftp> ls -lA
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwx------    2 1329     600          4096 Mar 15 01:00 .a
-rw-------    1 1329     600             0 Mar 15 01:00 .b
drwx------    2 1329     600          4096 Mar 15 01:00 a
drwx------    2 1329     600          4096 Mar 15 01:00 b

$ ls -lA
total 12
drwx------ 2 ________ ________ 4096 Mar 15 01:00 a
drwx------ 2 ________ ________ 4096 Mar 15 01:00 .a
drwx------ 2 ________ ________ 4096 Mar 15 01:00 b
-rw------- 1 ________ ________    0 Mar 15 01:00 .b
```

Comment: Ты про `ls -avl`?

Comment: Спасибо! Да простите мне мою невнимательность) -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо  don Rumata

```
-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```